# create multiple pages and click on a specific selector and open something on each page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

The idea that I wanna apply here is that I have a group of buttons of courses and I wanna click each one of them and go back to the other one to check the details of the course but this will too take too much time if I do it on a single page. so I decided that when I reach the page where the courses are there, I will duplicate the page where the courses are to the number of courses and each page should open a course and close it but seems that doesn't work well with me.

This is where I am trying to apply the idea

```
import { ElementHandle, Page as PuppeterrPage } from "puppeteer";
import puppeteer, { Browser } from "puppeteer";
import { Page } from "../Pages/Page";
import { grabData } from "./CoursesInfo";

async function wait(duration: number) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
  });
}

export async function openCourse(pages: PuppeterrPage[], browser: Browser) {
  const courseBtn =
    'a.base-navigation-button-content.themed-background-primary-alt-fill-only.theme-border-left-active[analytics-id="courses.base.navigation.handleBase.link"]';

  const courseOption: ElementHandle<HTMLAnchorElement> | null =
    await pages[0].waitForSelector(courseBtn); // Assuming the first page in the array is the one to be used for interaction

  await courseOption?.click();
  await pages[0].waitForNavigation();

  const coursesSection = 'section[id="course-columns-current"]';
  await pages[0].waitForSelector(coursesSection);

  await loadElements(pages[0]);

  await wait(1000);
  const courses = await pages[0].$$(
    'article[ng-if="!membership.course.ui.isExternal"]'
  );
  const numCourses = courses.length;

  const promises = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < numCourses; i++) {
    const newPagePromise = (async () => {
      const newPage = await new Page(browser).createPage();
      await newPage.goto(pages[0].url());
      await loadElements(Page.pages[i]);
      
    })();
    
    promises.push(newPagePromise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);


  await wait(5000);
  const clickPromises = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < numCourses; i++) {
    
    
    const clickPromise = (async (pageIndex) => {
      
      const coursesOnNewPage = await Page.pages[pageIndex].$$(
        'article[ng-if="!membership.course.ui.isExternal"]'
      );
      // Assuming you want to click on the course corresponding to the current index i
      const courseToClick = coursesOnNewPage[i - 1];
      await courseToClick.click();
    })(i);

    clickPromises.push(clickPromise);
  }

  // Wait for all click actions to complete
  await Promise.all(clickPromises);
  // await Promise.all(promisesClickEvents);
  console.log(Page.pages);
  console.log("Number of courses: ", numCourses);
}

async function loadElements(page: PuppeterrPage) {
  if (!page) {
    await wait(1500);
    await loadElements(page)
    return;
  }
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const table: NodeListOf<ChildNode> | undefined = document.querySelector(
      "#course-columns-current > div"
    )?.childNodes;
    let lastDiv;
    if (table) {
      for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i].nodeName == "DIV") {
          lastDiv = table[i];
        }
      }
    }
    lastDiv?.scrollIntoView();
  });
}
```

this is where the grabData function created:

```
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page as PuppeterrPage } from "puppeteer";

export async function grabData(page: PuppeterrPage) {
  await page.waitForSelector("#course-instructors-panel > ul");
  const button = "#view-all-button";

  const viewAllButton = await page.$(button);
  if (viewAllButton) {
    await viewAllButton.click();
    console.log("There are more than two instructors");
  } else {
    console.log("There are less than two instructors");
  }

  const instructors = await page.$$(
    "#course-instructors-panel > ul > li span.primary-text"
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < instructors.length; i++) {
    const instructor = await page.evaluate(
      (instructor) => instructor.textContent,
      instructors[i]
    );
    console.log("Instructor " + (i + 1) + ": " + instructor);
  }
}
```

This is the page class that I am using:

```
import puppeteer, {Browser, Page as PuppeterrPage} from "puppeteer";

export class Page {
    private browser: Browser;
    public static pages: PuppeterrPage[];

    constructor(browser: Browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
        Page.pages = [];
    }

    async createPage() {
        const page = await this.browser.newPage();
        Page.pages.push(page);
        return page;
    }

    async closePage(index: number): Promise<void> {
        if(index >= 0 && index < Page.pages.length) {
            await Page.pages[index].close();
            Page.pages.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid index");
        }
    }

    async closeAllPages(): Promise<void> {
        await Promise.all(Page.pages.map(page => page.close()));
        Page.pages = [];
    }
}
```

Let me just explain some of the parts of the first part of code :

```
for (let i = 1; i < numCourses; i++) {
    const newPagePromise = (async () => {
      const newPage = await new Page(browser).createPage();
      await newPage.goto(pages[0].url());
      await loadElements(Page.pages[i]);
      
    })();
    
    promises.push(newPagePromise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
```

in here , I tried to ducplicate the pages to the number of courses that should happend all at once and it worked

```
  const clickPromises = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < numCourses; i++) {
    
    
    const clickPromise = (async (pageIndex) => {
      
      const coursesOnNewPage = await Page.pages[pageIndex].$$(
        'article[ng-if="!membership.course.ui.isExternal"]'
      );
      // Assuming you want to click on the course corresponding to the current index i
      const courseToClick = coursesOnNewPage[i - 1];
      await courseToClick.click();
    })(i);

    clickPromises.push(clickPromise);
  }

  // Wait for all click actions to complete
  await Promise.all(clickPromises);
```

In here I tried to open once course in each page but that didn't work well with me I hope someone helps me

I tried it using many approached as I explained but I end having several problems like some of my pages are not loaded fully although I used this function:

```
async function loadElements(page: PuppeterrPage) {
  if (!page) {
    await wait(1500);
    await loadElements(page)
    return;
  }
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const table: NodeListOf<ChildNode> | undefined = document.querySelector(
      "#course-columns-current > div"
    )?.childNodes;
    let lastDiv;
    if (table) {
      for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i].nodeName == "DIV") {
          lastDiv = table[i];
        }
      }
    }
    lastDiv?.scrollIntoView();
  });
}
```

even it does , it doesn't open the courses . I am expecting to find a solution for that so that I am able to open one course in each page

Comment: Without the website, there's no real way to help here.

Comment: The problem is that even if I sent you the website, it will require me to send you my username and password. Isn't there any real way to help? @ggorlen

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. Every site is totally unique, so either I can spot an problem in the code, or I have to run it and play with it to see what's going on. I don't see any obvious issues in your code at a glance.

Comment: I can send the repo to you see it but what do you suggest about my creditentials being revealed? @ggorlen